# can't access some route because middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I'm new at Laravel and i'm currently following some tutorial. in those tutorial i create some middleware named Admin and in Admin middleware i make the code like here:

```
if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1) {

            Session::flash('success','U do not have access to this menu');
            return back();

}
```

and in my route i'm setting like this:

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/makeadmin', 'UsersController@admin')->name('users.makeadmin')->middleware('admin');
```

well it success for non admin, but when using admin i got blocked either although in user table i already set the admin into 1. so do i missing something or i'm doing it wrong? i'm currently using laravel 5.5.

Comment: You should wrap your Mware around anything that needs to have admin permissions (this will make life easier in the log haul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah sorry this is very stupid, i forgot to put "!" and that why i can't access the route although its admin already. so here's just what i do.

```
if (!Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin !== 1) {

            Session::flash('success','U do not have access to this menu');
            return back();

}
```

Comment: my concern here is that you've placed this into the controller and not the middleware? Could I be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Auth::check() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1)
        return $next($request); 
    Session::flash('success','U do not have access to this menu');
    return back();
}
```